# Can't send Bearer token in Karate

Tags: api, automation, authorization, karate, bearer-token

I have to use token in API test to delete some quote. I can adjust it in Postman, but unfortunately, can't do it with the help of Karate.
I get this error -> "...failed: connect timed out" and fail on method Delete.

Here the example:

> ```
> Feature: API Test
>
>   Background:
>     * def token = 'someToken'
>     
>   Scenario: Quote Deleting
>     * url 'URL?reference=AAA'
>     * header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token
>     And method delete
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sample, which works perfectly for me:

```
* def token = 'foo'
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token
* request { foo: 'bar' }
* method delete
```

Comment: Hi @Peter, If I have multiple API calls in one scenario then I have to set header each time I call new API right ? If I keep in Background that will only work for first call in the scenario and for second API call I am setting it again.

Comment: @Parashuram please read the docs on `configure headers`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#configure-headers - and you can even set it in `karate-config.js` so that it applies to all api calls